# Gatsby project giving strange errors and is unable to build

Tags: gatsby

I npm install --save gatsby-transformer-sharp gatsby-plugin-sharp and then after doing so I'm unable to run my project and I'm getting these strange errors:

```
(sharp:7804): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:10:08.042: cannot register existing type 'VipsObject'

(sharp:7804): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:10:08.043: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(sharp:7804): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:10:08.043: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(sharp:7804): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:10:08.043: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using npm? I switched to yarn because npm repeatedly threw errors like this when I added the sharp package. For Gatsby I recommend using yarn as a package manager because of these unexplainable errors. If you search github issues you will find a lot of package manager related issues with npm. yarn for whatever reason works more reliable. This is just my experience so do what you will.

Comment: Amazingly, switching to yarn worked.  I deleted everything in node_modules/ as well as package.json and installed through yarn and it worked.

Comment: I use yarn in my project and I am facing the same issue here.

Comment: Getting the same issue after upgrading to gatsby 2.1

Answer (score 4):

The error is caused by : gatsby-plugin-favicon , sharp was not updated on it, for now just uninstall it.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue (working with Yarn, not npm). It seems the wrong version of some binary was cached somewhere.

What fixed the issue for me was running `yarn cache clean`, removing the entire node_modules and installing all dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the npm ecosystem with breaking changes within versions. There are two possible solutions:

**1. Rebuild and switch dependency manager**

- use `gatsby clean`
- delete node_modules manually
- use [yarn instead of npm](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/)

Switching from npm to yarn might just solve it. If you search github issues you will find a lot of package manager related issues with npm. I can speak from my own experience that the simple switch worked in my case. yarn for whatever reason works more reliable. The gatsby maintainers recommend yarn for Gatsby development.

**2. Remove faulty plugins**

The thousands of packages depending on each other regularly introduce regression errors for each other. Removing dependencies one by one, `gatsby clean` + `yarn`, might be able to solve it. As @Zecide mentioned, start with `gatsby-plugin-favicon` if you use that.